# Creating Microsoft Excel Connections to SQL Server stored procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, sqlconnection

I am trying to create a connection to a SQL Server database to pull a table into Excel from a stored procedure. In previous versions of Excel, I was able to establish a connection, but now with the Excel 2016 it only allows it as a query. This is causing problems when I want to refresh a table.

[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if that functionality was carried over from Excel 2013 to 2016. Have you tried just scraping the query from the stored procedure and then just keeping it in your excel file to run when you want to refresh?